# R compare column across rows

Tags: r, compare

I have the following problem that is challenging to me since I am more or less a beginner in R.

I have a data.frame similar so this:

```
   a  b      c
1  x g1  date1
2  x g1  date2
3  y g2  date3
4  y g3  date4
5  y g4  date5
6  z g1  date6
7  z g2  date7
8  x g4  date8
9  y g1  date9
10 y g3 date10
```

What I would like to do is compare the 1st value in column `a` with the 2nd value. If they are the same then check in column b whether `g2` follows `g1`.

The data is sorted by date and I basically want to find the number of occurrences where `g2` follows `g1` while the corresponding values in column `a` are similar.

In the example data above the sum would be 1. (row 6 and 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is possible an easier way, but here's my `data.table` attempt

```
library(data.table) ## v 1.9.6+
setDT(df)[a == shift(a, type = "lead") & b == "g1" & shift(b, type = "lead") == "g2", .N]
## [1] 1
```

This is basically compares `a` against the shifted `a` column while checks that the `b` column equals to `g1` and the shifted `b` column equals to `g2`. You will need the latest `data.table` version on CRAN in order for this to work.

---

Using `dplyr` it could something among these lines

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(a == lead(a) & b == "g1" & lead(b) == "g2") %>%
  count()
# Source: local data table [1 x 1]
# 
#       n
#   (int)
# 1     1
```

---

Or with base R

```
sum(with(df, a == c(tail(as.character(a), -1), NA) & b == "g1" & c(tail(as.character(b), -1), NA) == "g2"))
## [1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative:

data:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text=' a  b      c
1  x g1  date1
2  x g1  date2
3  y g2  date3
4  y g3  date4
5  y g4  date5
6  z g1  date6
7  z g2  date7
8  x g4  date8
9  y g1  date9
10 y g3 date10', stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Solution:

```
library(dplyr) #for lag
#df$a == lag(df$a) checks the equality in consecutive rows in a
#the rest of the code checks the order of g2 and g1 in consecutive rows
df$out <- df$a == lag(df$a) &   grepl(paste('g2','g1'), paste(df$b, lag(df$b)))
```

Output:

```
> df
   a  b      c   out
1  x g1  date1 FALSE
2  x g1  date2 FALSE
3  y g2  date3 FALSE
4  y g3  date4 FALSE
5  y g4  date5 FALSE
6  z g1  date6 FALSE
7  z g2  date7  TRUE
8  x g4  date8 FALSE
9  y g1  date9 FALSE
10 y g3 date10 FALSE
```

And

```
sum(df$out)
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this.

```
result <- NULL
for (i in 1:NROW(df)){result <- c(result, df$a[i]==df$a[i-1] & df$b[i]=="g2" & df$b[i-1]=="g1")}
length(which(result))
# [1] 1
```

This is the data.

```
a <- c("x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "x", "y", "y")
b <- c("g1", "g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "g1", "g2", "g4", "g1", "g3")
c <- paste("date", 1:10, sep = "")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
```